# Python Selenium find element javascript

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

in page

https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/upload

a need click "Choose file" but I have Message: javascript error: argument is not defined

```
var1 = sys.argv[1]
path = os.path.abspath(var1)    

driver.get("https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/upload")

element = driver.execute_script('return document.querySelector("#view-container > home-view").shadowRoot.querySelector("#uploadForm").shadowRoot.querySelector("#infoIcon").shadowRoot.querySelector("#wrapperLink")')
driver.execute_script('argument[0].click();', element)
```

How to define this element. I would like to send a file to check using the script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something that works.

```
element = driver.execute_script('return document.querySelector("#view-container > home-view").shadowRoot.querySelector("#uploadForm").shadowRoot')
file_element = element.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#fileSelector")
file_element.send_keys(r"your_file_path/filename.extn")
```

It submits the file from the backend without clicking on the button and opening the file dialog.

Alternate code:

```
def open_shadow_root(element):
    shadow_root = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot', element)
    return shadow_root

driver.get("https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/upload")
time.sleep(5)
root_1 = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#view-container > home-view")
sroot_1 = open_shadow_root(root_1)
print(sroot_1)
time.sleep(4)
root_2 = sroot_1.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#uploadForm")
sroot_2 = open_shadow_root(root_2)
time.sleep(4)
file_element = sroot_2.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#fileSelector")
file_element.send_keys(r"your_file_path/filename.extn")
time.sleep(4)
driver.quit()
```

It does the same job as the previous code; it's just that I have written a shadow root function and utilizing it to open the shadow roots. This looks a little more readable in my opinion, but there is no stopping from using the former code.
Also, I have used `time.sleep()` which can be replaced with `WebdriverWait` if possible.

If you still want to click on the `Choose File` button and work through the file dialog, then you may try the below:

```
element = driver.execute_script('return document.querySelector("#view-container > home-view").shadowRoot.querySelector("#uploadForm").shadowRoot')

choose_file = element.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#infoIcon")
choose_file.click()
```

Alternate:

```
def open_shadow_root(element):
    shadow_root = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot', element)
    return shadow_root


driver.get("https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/upload")
time.sleep(4)
root_1 = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#view-container > home-view")
sroot_1 = open_shadow_root(root_1)
print(sroot_1)
time.sleep(4)
root_2 = sroot_1.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#uploadForm")
sroot_2 = open_shadow_root(root_2)
time.sleep(4)
choose_file = sroot_2.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#infoIcon")
choose_file.click()
# ... choose the file ....

driver.quit()
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I see that I still have to meet a lot. I'm just starting from Selenium. And how to call Confirm Upload

Comment: :)

    file_element = sroot_2.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#fileSelector")
    file_element.send_keys(var1)
    time.sleep(2)
    root_3 = sroot_2.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#confirmUpload")
    root_3.click()